# PHP echo to li table from input text file

Tags: php, html-lists, echo

I have input from user which I get from method Post and I place that input to text file. Separated with semicolon (;). And each new input makes a new line in text file. Now I want to read that input from text file and echo it out to li in HTML. I am having problems to echo it the right way.

Here is input PHP-code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $title = $_POST['movieTitle'];
        $rating = $_POST['movieRatings'];
        $plot = $_POST['plot']; 
    $handle = fopen('movies.txt', 'a');
    $names_array = array("$title","$rating","$plot");
    $string = implode(';', $names_array);
    fwrite($handle, $string."\n");          
    fclose($handle);
    }   
    ?>
```

This code above works fine, now the problem is mentioned below when I read from text file.

```
 <ul class="movies" id="Movies">
  $filename = 'movies.txt';

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

    $datain = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); 

    $names_array = explode(';', $datain);

    foreach($names_array as $name)
    {
    echo '<li>'.$name.'</li>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

This echo's out all the reading from file in new line. Like this:

```
<li>Movie Title1</li>
<li>Movie Ratings1</li>
<li>Plot 1</li>
<li>Movie Title2</li>
<li>Movie Ratings2</li>
<li>Plot 2</li>
<li>Movie Title3</li>
<li>Movie Ratings3</li>
<li>Plot 3</li>
```

I want to have the same li line for every line from the text file, something like this:

```
<li>Movie Title1, MovieRatings1, Plot1</li>
<li>Movie Title2, MovieRatings2, Plot2</li>
<li>Movie Title3, MovieRatings3, Plot3</li>
```

etc.
I am new to PHP, so I am not so good with arrays and loops in PHP. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would help if you pasted us a sample of the input data to help clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `explode()` the file on newlines `"\n"` first. Loop through that array and in the inner loop, `explode()` on the semicolons. Like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $datain);
foreach($lines as $line){
    list($title,$ratings,$plot) = explode(";", $line, 3);
    // echo <li>s with $title,$ratings,$plot here
}
```

It is worth looking into PHP's `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` functions, they are designed to do exactly what you are doing manually.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I get this syntax error code when I try your code:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING)
It is on the foreach line, the error. Thanks

Comment: 'in' is a pythonism, you need `foreach ($lines as $line)`, have ammeded submitters code

Comment: Thanks Catharsis, I have it working now except that I get Notice: Undefined offset: 1 and Undefined offset: 2 it is in this line: list($title,$ratings,$plot) = explode(";",$line,3); that I get a notice!

Comment: You have a blank line in your data at the end, it's trying to explode this into 3 parts and set $ratings and $plot equal to the second and third part. You could `rtrim()` the newline from the file or change your input code to append the newline before your data instead of after it.